# Is there a name for a non-circular annulus (a shape missing part of the interior)?

Tags: geometry

According to Wikipedia, "In mathematics, an annulus (plural annuli or annuluses) is the region between two concentric circles. Informally, it is shaped like a ring or a hardware washer."

Is there another formal name to describe generic 2D shapes (not just circles) that have a section missing in the interior?

For example, could you call the shapes below elliptical or rectangular annuli? Or is there a better descriptor?

Thanks for your help!

[image: What would you call these shapes? Elliptical or rectangular annuli?]

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I heard of the _punctured disc_ when just a point is missing. If the boundaries were concentric, maybe one could speak of annuli in different norms. Maybe ring-shaped?

Comment: Thanks @Invisible, I hadn't heard of that before. But I think a punctured disc is technically still an annulus (assuming it is the center point missing) -- the inner radius is just zero.

Comment: [Here](https://images.app.goo.gl/mv8xY4HV5gWbBNCp6) they speak of different annuli

Comment: Another interesting find, thanks, and getting closer! I guess I'm looking for something still more generic, as shown in my figure. The shapes don't have to be concentric or have boundaries that are equidistant around the entire boundary.

Comment: In a recent paper I saw they used the term annulus to refer to a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a ball removed (so not just a standard annulus). I guess you can go with 'generalized annulus'.

Comment: Are the shapes required to be similar?

Comment: "Topological annulus"? see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936688/path-homotopy-in-a-topological-annulus and https://www.google.com/search?q=%22topological+annulus%22

Comment: @robphy no the shapes don't have to be similar. the more generic the better!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the best answer so far is "topological annulus," as suggested by @robphy.

Following [Path Homotopy in a Topological Annulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936688/path-homotopy-in-a-topological-annulus), the following definition corresponds to what I was describing:

"Let $_1$ and $_2$ be simple, closed curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $_1$ lies in the region bounded by $_2$, and the origin $$ lies in the region bounded by $_1$. Define an annulus $$ as the region bounded by and including $_1$ and $_2$."